# ¿Insertar una imagen a un marcador de word desde MS Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

tengo un formulario en MS Visual Basic desde el cual los datos ingresados en el, se insertan en unos marcadores que tengo en una plantilla de word, estoy tratando ahora de insertar una imagen, que tengo en un picture box y la cargo a través de un botón enlazado a un openfiledialog con el siguiente código:

```
  Private Sub btncargar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncargar.Click
            'cargaimagen.InitialDirectory = "C:\users"
            If cargaimagen.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                pb1.Image = Image.FromFile(cargaimagen.FileName)
                ruta = cargaimagen.FileName
                imagenempresa = pb1.Image
                MsgBox(ruta)
            End If
        End Sub
```

> ```
> Al momento de insertar la información ingresada en el formulario a los marcadores de word uso el siguiente código:
> ```

```
'funcion para agregar valores a los marcadores ya creados en el archivo word
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("valortotal").Range.Text = valorpersonal
                'funcion para agregar valor en letras al word
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("valorletras").Range.Text = valorletras
                'funcion para asignar el numero de dias del plazo de entrega
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("diasletras").Range.Text = diasletras
                'funcion para asignar dias en letras 
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("dias").Range.Text = plazoentrega
                'funcion para asignar la fecha
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("fecha").Range.Text = fecha
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("fecha2").Range.Text = fecha
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("fecha3").Range.Text = fecha
                'Bloque donde se añade los datos del cliente en los respectivos marcadores de la plantilla word
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("nombrecliente").Range.Text = nombrecliente
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("correocliente").Range.Text = correocliente
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("empresacliente").Range.Text = empresacliente
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("referencia").Range.Text = referenciaestudio
                documento.Bookmarks.Item("logo").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(ruta, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
```

Sin embargo la ultima linea:

```
documento.Bookmarks.Item("logo").Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(ruta, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
```

no me muestra error alguno, pero no inserta la imagen en el marcador propuesto para esta. ¿Como podria hacerlo?

Answer (score -1):

espero aún te sirva

```
Dim MSWord As New Word.Application

MSWord.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=(Ruta), LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.